# when to use Action bar and sherlockActionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am newbie in Android and in this forum too. i don't know when to use Action bar and `sherlockActionbar`. i am using `Api` 16 . Can someone please explain here? Thanks in advance.

#### Updated :please tell me how to customize my Action bar. i don't wanna show my app icon in left side of action bar and also want s to change the color and put the image over there??

Comment: add this line : getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

Comment: where in need to add this line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Action bar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html) is `build for API Level 11 or higher` so that will not run below that API version.

**Note:**

> This class is included in the support library for compatibility with API level 7 and higher. If you're developing your app for API level 11 and higher only, you should instead use the framework ActionBar class.

[ActionBar Support Lib / ActionBarCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) That has released by Google for older version also.

> We released a new backward-compatible Action Bar implementation called ActionBarCompat that's part of the Support Library r18. The ActionBarCompat APIs let you build the essential Action Bar design pattern into your app, with broad compatibility back to Android 2.1.

[ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is library project which support in lower version. `Minimum API level is 7`

In your case, 
If your `android:minSDK="16"`  then you should go with ActionBar. but ,

If you want to set your `android:minSDK="10"` or below then that , in that case you should use ActionbarSherlock.

Comment: please give me solution for my updated question.

Comment: You should ask other question, or try to find may be that is already ask by someone.

Comment: you can also use ActionbarSherlock API 7 to API 19.

Comment: @PavelDudka Yes, i knew that ,check my updates, but my answer is not wrong as well if you have gave me down vote then.

Answer (score 0):

For sherlockActionbar, you should build your application with SDK version 14 or above.

> Due to its use of the native action bar and its related classes on Ice
>   Cream Sandwich, the library requires that both it and your project are
>   compiled with Android 4.0 or newer. The project also requires that you
>   are compiling with JDK 1.6 in both your editor and any build systems
>   that you may be using.

And if  you check out the support library at: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

If you are using Support Library v7 or above:

```
New v7 appcompat library:
Added ActionBar to allow implementation of the action bar user interface design pattern back to Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher. Use of this class requires that you implement your activity by extending the new ActionBarActivity class.
```

It is built in with Action Bar and you can use it safely without externally including SherlockActionBar.

> Note: v7 appcompat library depends on the v4 Support Library. If you are using
>   Ant or Eclipse, make sure you include the v4 Support Library as part
>   of this library's classpath.

Of course you have to use Sherlock if you are still using v4 support library solely.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your updated question:

If you want to remove app icon from action bar then just remove this line from Manifest file in application tag

```
android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
```

If you wanna change that image just put one image in drawable folder and replace **app_icon** with that image name which is present in the drawable folder

```
android:icon="@drawable/your_image_name"
```

To change color refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground) link